Flutter Gradle Version Incompatible with Java Version: How to Fix?
I’m facing an issue with my Flutter project where the Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using. When I try to build the project, I get the following error:
┌─ Flutter Fix ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using   │
│ for Gradle.                                                                                     │
│                                                                                                 │
│ If you recently upgraded Android Studio, consult the migration guide at                         │
│ https://flutter.dev/to/java-gradle-incompatibility.                                             │
│                                                                                                 │
│ Otherwise, to fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter │
│ doctor --verbose`.                                                                              │
│                                                                                                 │
│ Then, update the Gradle version specified in C:\PROJECT                                         │
│ FLUTTER\note\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to be compatible with that Java   │
│ version. See the link below for more information on compatible Java/Gradle versions:            │
│ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java                               │
2
│                                                                                                 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

help me I keep on getting gradle issue for few days now out of the blue, now i cant submit my assignment on time.
What I have tried:

Ran flutter doctor --verbose to check the Java version used by Flutter.
Updated the Gradle version in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to match the Java version.
Verified that the Gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties is compatible with the Java version.
Rebuilt the project after making the changes, but the issue persists.
downloaded jdk 11, 17 , and 21 and set environment variable path one by one.
using extension Pack for Java. maybe im not using it correctly? maybe i have to do something after i install it? i tried with jdk 17 only, and then change gradle version based on the version i use with this extension.

